# Django is keep throwing error timestamp is invalid

Tags: python, django

I have this in model

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

and form is this

```
timestamp = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I am using jquery DateTimePicker [given here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) with this

```
 $( ".datepicker input" ).datetimepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ',
 });
```

But Django keeps throwing the error `date format not valid`. It works sometime when I select a random date. but I am not exactly sure when it works.

Comment: How about you keep a note of which ones it says are invalid and which ones it does not. That way you can tell what the difference is.

Comment: Maybe this is the problem. You're saying that your DateTimeField must accept dates with the following format: '2006-10-25 14:30:59' but in your datepicker, you have something like 06-10-25. Obviously that would throw an error in your Django field.

Comment: By default, jquery comes with a datepicker and not with a datetimepicker. So which is the plugin you are using to get datetimepicker? Provide link to that. And try to avoid spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Robert , when i do `yyyy` in datepicker , it comes as `20122102`. when i use `yy` then it come as `2012`. i don't know why

Comment: @user1758043 - i believe that there is not such setting as yyyy. When you want to show only two year digits use 'y'

Comment: @arulmrr I am using this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: Can i use some django widget for datetime picking rather than jquery

Comment: @user1758043 If you are using custom django template, then you need to use jquery for datetimepicker.

Comment: Well, there you have your problem. If your jquery plugin is the problem, try to change your DateTimeField.

Comment: @Robert , i dodn't get it what you mean , change field to what?

Comment: Change the format of your DateTimeField. Maybe you don't need DateTimeField. For example, it could be that DateField is enough for your needs. Other option is to manipulate your datepicker's output into a format so you can use it in DateField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django settings allow you to define your date input format. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATE_FORMAT). Check that the date / datetime format that is submitted by your jQuery script is "allowed" and override the default settings if you need to.

The default datetime input formats are:

```
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d',
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y',
'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y')
```

The dates you are sending back to the server clearly do not comply with this.